# What is linux peth* and virbr* network interface?

Tags: networking, centos

Usually when execute `ifconfig` I got the "usual" network interfaces: **wlan0**, **eth0** and **lo**.

Those, I suppose to be my PC's wireless adaptor, ethernet adaptor and localhost.
I'm using a remote server that has the following interfaces:

- eth0
- eth1
- lo
- peth0
- peth1
- virbr0

What those peth* and virbr mean?

Comment: Seems to me that `virbr*` is a virtual bridge interface like those used by virtual machines to access the host's physical NICs

Comment: ... and peth* are those physical interfaces. http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_Networking#Bridging

Answer (score 1):

Peth is Xens name for "Physical Ethernet".  With Xen distributions, custom naming rules were set up due to the large number of physical and virtual devices on a system.

However, most linux flavors these days using systemd are going to have rules defined that ensure the interface gets its same name across reboots.  This is due to the growing number of systems with multiple interfaces - and is designed to protect against NIC1 being named "Eth0", but then getting named "Eth1" after a reboot.  You can see the rules for this in /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/ - the rules that apply to the network interfaces are in 80-net-name-slot.rules.

You can even create a custom version of this so your devices all get named after Peanuts characters, if you'd like.  Thats part of Systemd and udev rules.